# Big-list questions - should we tolerate them early on, to build content for tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, close-reasons

Prompted by [Good documentary videos related to the sustainable living?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1015/48) , I've commented:

> as it's phrased at the moment, there isn't a single definitive answer: it could only be answered by a big list. On the other hand, in their early days, many sites do seem to allow these big-list questions, with the content then getting fed into tag wikis.

Once the site is mature, I'm taking it for granted that our policy will be to close & delete such questions.

However, on other sites, these seem to have been a good way in the early days to gather great content and attract new users.

So, what shall we do **now, while the site is young**?

Comment: Seems to be related to http://meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/126/allow-or-not-what-are-the-most-influential-canonical-must-read-books-on-su

Comment: @boo2060 good point. Indeed, this can be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**Respected @EnergyNumbers thanx for your concerned**

In my opinion any site/portal can not to be recognized either young & mature on the basis of How much numbers of the users it have. Its depends upon the understanding, knowledge of the user's who are coming on there & How responsibly they are asking & answering the questions.
As this question is seem to be not such definitive answer but it collect the efforts of individual to be gather, to view the collective & holistic approach of what to be solution, where we are stand of, etc.

**At early stage suggestion as from my point of view**

1)We have to be chat together at particular time period to be conclude in such a manner to derive a solution of our problems.

2)All the users(593) almost at today present have feeling of Relationship with each other. Good things is there are such amount of the people's  present who have concerned with the sustainable living so if all have live in sustain ably we definitely helpful for others to live a better life.

3)ALL we have want to be live in a UNDIVIDED Society ON THIS EARTH So anything who worthily to achieve that I think that should be publish & that is always very definite in amount.

Comment: I believe what EnergyNumbers was referring to was the age/maturity of this particular SE The sustainable site.  Some categories are in their infancy as others have been on SE for a long time.  I am very new to the SE & for the most part had very positive experiences as people are here to help out of the goodness of their hearts really. EnergyNumbers has been nothing but respectful, helpful & patient to this newbie in my experiences. I like your points. I don't believe anyone suggested deleting catalog type answers rather moving from Q & A to Wiki.

Comment: see above (swore I put your name at the beginning)